# Flutter app crashing after Firebase logout

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, riverpod

iam still really new to Flutter. Iam using Riverpod together with Firebase and getting some crash after trying to logout. If someone could help it would be awesome! If its just a noob mistake iam sorry already:D

My main.dart looks like this:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: App()));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for Errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("Error"));
        }

        // Once complete, show application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: MyApp(),
            darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          );
        }

        // Otherwise, show loadin while waiting for init to complete
        return LoadingScreen();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then i have this short app.dart file.

```
class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final userAsyncValue = watch(authStateChangesProvider);

    return userAsyncValue.when(
        data: (user) {
          if (user == null) {
            return LoginScreen();
          } else {
            return HomeScreen();
          }
        },
        loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (_, __) => Container());
  }
}
```

I have a providers file

```
final firebaseAuthProvider = Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);

final authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) => ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges());
```

and an AuthService file:

```
class AuthenticationService {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future logInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  Future logOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

finally my Login Page looks like this just

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final _inputService = InputService();
    final _emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
    final _passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
    final _auth = AuthenticationService();

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Email", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  controller: _emailcontroller,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) => _inputService.isInputValid(value, "email")),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                obscureText: true,
                controller: _passwordcontroller,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                validator: (value) => _inputService.isInputValid(value, "password"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      _auth.logInWithEmailAndPassword(_emailcontroller.text, _passwordcontroller.text);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    "Login",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and a real simple home screen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final _auth = AuthenticationService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _auth.logOut();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Logout",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Logging in works like a charm but as soon as i logout the app crashes and i just got a exited (sigterm) if you tell me how i can find more debug information in vscode i happily supply it:D

Also it actually seems to correctly log me out of Firebase, at least when reopening the app on the simulator iam back in the login screen. So i guess its something with the auth state change and rebuild of the ConsumerWidget in the MyApp class?

Would be awesome if someone could help! And if you think my code sucks in general be happy to correct me iam just trying to put together what i find in tutorials and always are happy to be corrected:D

Edit:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "^1.0.1"
  firebase_auth: "^1.0.1"
  flutter_riverpod: "^0.13.1+1"
```

Comment: I just noticed that the logout indeed seems to work i see for a quarter second the Loginscreen again before it crashes.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Do you get an error in your console? I am facing a similar problem. Flutter app just closes with Exited (sigterm) right after Lost connection to device. I use the same dependencies.

Comment: Getting the same behaviour as well. Any progress ?

Comment: @john, @kilian I was on the beta branch and I could verify that this is because of the `obscureText` variable in the `TextFormField`. If I removed the line in my code the app stopped crashing.
I filed a bug: [Flutter GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79199).
For now, I switched to the stable channel where everything works as expected!

Comment: I just switched to android emulator and it works fine for me. I just thought its maybe an emulator problem since iam also runnung on the M1 and wanted to test it at some time on another machine. Thanks for finding out the obscureText Problem though and reporting it!

Comment: Did you solve it?